Getting POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/generate 405 (Method Not Allowed) - express - cors
I'm trying to input json into an html box, and have the json get html from a folder called 'modules', and return the output as a preview in the html. I'm getting an error in the request. POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/generate 405 (Method Not Allowed) I cannot figure this out, any help would be great. I think i just keep guessing and have messed up the code now. Am i not pointing to the localhost correctly? I'm using http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Thanks.
app.js:
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Enable CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

// Define your routes here

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 127.0 .0 .1: 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

import cors from 'cors';
// Enable CORS for specific origin
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' // Change this to your frontend URL
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

// Route to handle form submission and generate HTML
app.post('/generate', (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Get JSON input from request body
        const jsonInput = req.body;

        // Generate HTML based on parsed JSON data
        const htmlOutput = generateHtml(jsonInput);

        // Return HTML response
        res.send(htmlOutput);
    } catch (error) {
        // Return error message if JSON parsing fails
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
});

// Function to generate HTML based on parsed JSON data
function generateHtml(parsedData) {
    // Implement the logic to generate HTML from parsed JSON data
    return "Generated HTML";
}

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

HTML:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML Generator</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS for split layout */
        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
        .left {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .right {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .preview {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML Generator</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Left side for JSON input -->
        <div class="left">
            <h2>Input JSON</h2>
            <textarea id="json_input" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br>
            <button onclick="updatePreview()">Generate HTML</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Right side for HTML preview -->
        <div class="right">
            <h2>Preview</h2>
            <div class="preview" id="html_preview"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript for live preview -->
    <script>
        const jsonInput = document.getElementById('json_input');
        const htmlPreview = document.getElementById('html_preview');
    
        // Function to update HTML preview
        function updatePreview() {
            try {
                // Call Express route to generate HTML
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/generate', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ json_input: jsonInput.value })
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Failed to fetch HTML');
                    }
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(htmlData => {
                    console.log('Received HTML data:', htmlData);
                    htmlPreview.innerHTML = htmlData;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    htmlPreview.innerHTML = `<p>Error: ${error.message}</p>`;
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                htmlPreview.innerHTML = `<p>Error: ${error.message}</p>`;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>


There is 2 app.listen() calls, only one should be there. cors also called twice. include this line app.use(express.json())
